# Is an Integration Service Environment required for a Logic App to talk to a SQL Database in our Azure tenancy?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have scheduled tasks (C# Console Apps) that perform a number of operations like User synchronization between our AD and a users table in our application.  These live on a SQL Server that is being retired so I want to move them into Azure.  It sounds like Logic Apps is the way I want to go.  As I'm standing things up I'm reading documentation that says an Integration Service Environment is the right way to go and others that say I can just stand up the logic app and it will do fine communicating with our SQL Server on its own.  Can someone answer this question for me or point me in the direction of the documentation that compares the two approaches?

Comment: Indeed logic apps can do what you need oob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Logic App can talk to a Azure SQL Database fine.  One can even talk to On-premise databases through the use of the On-Premise Data Gateway.  An ISE can be nice if the costs are worth it but we find one too expensive for our needs.  Simple Logic Apps work fine.

Comment: Thanks Scott, Azure is a blast once you figure everything out.  There sure is a lot of everything though...